# vscode + vim: commenting line doesn't move cursor down

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

How to make Visual Studio Code move my cursor one line down, after commenting current line with `ctrl + /` shortcut? I tried (in user settings):

```json
"vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
    {
        "before": ["<C+/>"],
        "after": ["<C+/>", "j"]
    }
]
```

but it doesn't work.

Using Linux Manjaro + vscode 1.27.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for current vscode (1.48.0):

1. Install this extension: `geddski.macros`
2. Add this line to `settings.json`:

```json
"macros": { "commentLine": ["editor.action.commentLine","cursorDown"] },
```

3. Add these lines to `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+/",
    "command": "macros.commentLine",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
```

**How to quickly open these files:**

- For `keybindings.json` press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+p</kbd> and write `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`
- For `settings.json` press above shortcut and write `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`

---

**Physical location of files:**
Linux:

- `~/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json`
- `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

Windows:

- `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\keybindings.json`
- `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`

MacOS:

- `~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/keybindings.json`
- `~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json`

Comment: I'll edit the answer to add the `keybindings.json` location in the answer, but till then use these below:

Comment: for linux: `~/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json`

Comment: for windows: `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\keybindings.json`

Comment: Did'nt Work For Me Vs Code Throw An Error Command  `macros.commentLine` Not Found

Comment: @Farhad I edited the answer, adding proper macro to `settings.json`. Try it now.

Comment: For those who are lazy to deal with changing 2 config JSONs, there is a dedicated extension that does the requested job _only_ and requires _zero config_: 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shawtung.vscode-commentlinedown

I've just spend 15min spotting my error after copy-pasting the answer above: on MacOS `ctrl` is `cmd` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you check the `keybindings.json` (Click the gear icon) search `comment`
You will find there is a `Toggle Line Comment` Command there.
So you may need to disable it first.